# Inside a class, access Dictionary values in one function from another

Tags: python

I have a module which has a class and two functions in it.
func2 is invoked first and it creates dictionaries from SQL output.
I want to access values in these dictionaries to write it to file inside func1.

I tried to search for answers but couldn't locate my scenario so posting this question.

```
import sys
import os 
import abc as var

class test():

        def func1(self,A,B,C):
                csv=sample.csv
                print>>csv,"Value in dict from other function,",<not sure how to call>.tgt_dict3['table_name']
                <do something else>

        def func2(self,x,y,z):
                <do something not related to issue>
                #Call function collect_var and pass same arguments which this function received
                #This function takes input and runs query on SQL and returns dictionaries with column name and values
                (dict1,dict2,dict3)=var.collect_var(x,y,z)  

                 tgt_dict1=dict1[0]
                 tgt_dict2=dict2[0]
                 tgt_dict3=dict3[0]
```

Comment: ... pass the dictionaries as arguments to the method, or use an instance attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Like juanpa.arrivillaga states, you can either pass the dictionaries as arguments, or make them class/object attributes. Since you are not returning them I'll assume that they should be class attributes. This can be done as shown below. I'll be honest though, I don't believe that you looked hard enough before asking this question as this would be found in any class tutorial.

```
import sys
import os 
import abc as var

class test():
    tgt_dict1 = {}
    tgt_dict2 = {}        
    tgt_dict3 = {}

    def func1(self,A,B,C):
            csv=sample.csv
            print>>csv,"Value in dict from other function,",test.tgt_dict3['table_name']
            <do something else>

    def func2(self,x,y,z):
            <do something not related to issue>
            #Call function collect_var and pass same arguments which this function receive
            #This function takes input and runs query on SQL and returns dictionaries with column name and values
            (dict1,dict2,dict3)=var.collect_var(x,y,z)  

             test.tgt_dict1=dict1[0]
             test.tgt_dict2=dict2[0]
             test.tgt_dict3=dict3[0]
```

Comment: Um, you aren't actually using the class variables in your method. Also, why not instance variables? I think that's a more reasonable assumption instead of class variables

Comment: The scoping should have worked, but I've changed it to be explicit. The reason for using a static class versus an instance is due to how they were defining the functions and how it looked like they may be called.

Comment: David, I did find the answer where I can pass these as arguments but I am looking for a solution where I don't need to pass it as an argument. 

But looks like it is not possible to simply use it without declaring it at class level. (I was hoping to find something similar to" __main__".

As per your recommended solution I am assuming I will have to define these dictionaries as global inside the func1. I was reading some warnings against using global variables but as I am not trying to change these and only use it I am hoping that I should be fine. I will keep you posted.

Comment: These variables are not global nor do they need to be declared as such. They are class variables. They will work with the code written above. I would suggest checking out a class/object tutorial for python if you're confused about it.